# salesforce SCIM APIs documentation

Tags: rest-api, user-management

Does anyone know where I can find SCIM api documentation for salesforce? I have been trying hard for weeks but could not find a single document (other than their blog on them supporting SCIM). Is it that we have to buy some kind of enterprise edition in order to get access to these documentations?

All help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. I assume you're talking about identity management. Salesforce provides information on using their systems as Identity Providers (IdP) and Service Providers (SP). Can you explain exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: Mike! Thanks for the reply back! I am actually looking for all the possible documentation that salesforce has on it's SCIM provisioning/de-provisioning implementations. I am at my wit's end googling about it and I couldn't find a single document that provides me with the following details
1) Enable SCIM for my salesforce domain
2) SCIM implementation details for developers to use salesforce SCIM rest apis
3) SCIM java client (if any) provided by salesforce
Can you by any chance provide us with these details? Thanks!

Comment: Using SF as an IdP - http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=identity_provider_enable.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Some OAuth links - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_authenticate.htm&language=en

Comment: I am looking for Cloud Directory Services for salesforce. Here's the salesforce blogpost on it:
http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2012/09/introducing-salesforce-identity.html

Answer (score 1):

The Salesforce SCIM Service Provider implementation is documented in [Use the System for Cross-Domain Identity Management (SCIM)](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=identity_scim_overview.htm).