# Salesforce API for SCIM provider is available?

Tags: oauth, identity

I'm trying to write connector for WSO2 Identity Server which provision users to Salesforce. To do that i needed to find Salesforce SCIM endpoints for Users and Groups etc.

I believe Salesforce acting as SCIM provider is currently integrated and available since Salesforce has successfully done inter-op in Cloud Identity Summit (CIS) back in July this year.

For the inter-op it had been use endpoints as `https://MY_DOMAIN/services/apexrest/scim/v1/Users` etc. But relevant endpoints for my (developer) account giving me `401 Unauthorized`.

And i have tried `https://MY_DOMAIN/services/data/v26.0/scim/v1/users` which is shown as in [2] return the same as above.

I using curl to call those endpoints with authorization both Bearer and OAuth.
Ex: `curl -v -k --header 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' https://MY_DOMAIN/services/apexrest/scim/v1/Users`

So i am not sure what are the real endpoints are and how they secured.

Haven't found much resources related to this area which is also asked in [1].

Thanks in advance

DarRay

[1] [salesforce SCIM APIs documentation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17532/salesforce-scim-apis-documentation)

[2] http://www.slideshare.net/metadaddy/salesforce-identity-workshop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCIM is in pilot. Email cmortimore@salesforce.com to have it enabled in your org.